# Formating awk output to json using jq

Tags: bash

I'm using `grep` to search for specific text inside multiple files.

```
grep -n -r "text_to_match" *
```

The output is:

```
john:15
Hana:11
```

After that, am using `awk` to print whatever meets my criteria of the condition

```
grep -n -r "text_to_match" * | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1,$2}'
```

I want now to use `jq` to have the following json document

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "age": 15
    },
    {
      "name": "Hana",
      "age": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried the following:

```
jq -R 'split(" ") | { file:.[0], start_line:.[1]}'
```

Output

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "age": 15
}
{
  "name": "Hana",
  "age": 11
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `jq` can also do the splitting, you could start before doing it with `awk`, having

```
john:15
Hana:11
```

Then, with `-R` you can read in the raw lines. Using `-n` in combination with `[inputs]` makes it an array. You can split using the `/` operator, and wrap everything in an object of your choice.

```sh
jq -Rn '{data: [inputs / ":" | {name: .[0], age: .[1]}]}'
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "john",
      "age": "15"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hana",
      "age": "11"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/c8DC1IlKJe)

Comment: You could also use awk to do the text match, thus leaving only awk and jq in the pipeline.